# Передача данных между приложениями

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c++, сокет

В VS12 есть два приложения в одном решении. Одно является главным, второе консольным. Хотелось бы, чтобы консольное приложение являлось дебаг-консолью для основного. Как это можно реализовать - передачу данных между двумя приложениями?

Comment: Сокеты, именнованные каналы (pipe) пробовали?

Comment: Я как раз таки в этом ничего не понимаю, поэтому и попросил помощь сообщества

Comment: А зачем вообще второе приложение? Консоль можно создать вручную: `AllocConsole`. И дальше с ней можно работать обычными средствами: `ReadConsole` и `WriteConsole`. Для диагностики приложения - как раз само то.

Comment: ну, это хороший способ, не знал, но сокеты\трубы все равно когда-либо понадобятся

Answer (score 6):

Если разработка ведется под .NET, то посмотрите на WCF и .NET Remoting - избавит от необходимости низкоуровневого программирования сокетов.

Answer (score 4):

Задача разбивается на несколько подзадач:

1. выбрать канал для передачи данных,
2. создать свой протокол (как можно проще) для общения приложений,
3. выбрать формат сообщений для передачи данных.

Для C# на Windows под .NET подходят:

1. [использование именованных каналов для взаимодействия между процессами по сети](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546085.aspx)
2. - в зависимости от задачи,
3. сериализация произвольных классов в JSON с помощью, например, [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Comment: предположительно, обе части программы будут запущены на одной машине, так что не надо думать о сетевой синхронизации

Comment: ну тогда расскажите по подробнее про ваши именованые трубы

Answer (score 0):

Взаимодействие между различными приложениями может осуществляться по разному, например, через сокеты. Но в .NET 4.0 была введена новая функциональность, которая представляет собой создание участка общей разделяемой памяти для приложений. Далее читайте по ссылке https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/4.php
В .NET Core 3.1 я тестировал и всё работает отлично!)